# Dropdown list value not being passed with the model to controller after submitting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

The problem that i am facing is that when i submit this form the value of my dropdown is not passed to controller like the value of other text boxes.

I have a class :

```
public class NewCourseClassModel
{
    public Cours CourseModel { get; set; }
    public CourseDescription CourseDescriptionModel { get; set; }
    public CoursesDetail CoursesDetailModel { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ExistingCourseClass()
{
       var model = new NewCourseClassModel() { };
       ViewBag.Course_ID = new SelectList(db.Courses, "Course_ID", "Course_Name");
       ViewBag.Course_Name = new SelectList(db.Courses, "Course_Name", "Course_Name");
       return View(model);
}
```

On my view's page :

```
<div class="editor-field form">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Course_Name", "Select...")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseModel.Course_Name)
                </div>
```

Comment: You not binding to a model property. Use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseModel.Course_Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.Course_Name, "Select...")`

Comment: Your use of `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` suggests that you want the select name to be "CourseModel.Course_Name", while you are only passing "Course_Name" to `Html.DropDownListFor()`. This causes the model binder to not be able to find the `Course_Name`, leaving it empty in your model. Try `@Html.DropDownList("CourseModel.Course_Name", "Select...")`, or use a proper lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@html.DropdownListFor` like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseModel.Course_Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.Course_Name, "Select...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Html.DropDownList("Course_Name", "Select...")
```

Use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and bind dropdown with a model property as shown below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseModel.Course_Name, ViewBag.Course_Name as SelectList, "Select...")
```